# ActivatedRoute undefined for custom button click

Tags: angular, jqgrid

The following code instantiates `jqgrid` along with a custom button once the columnModel is available. This works fine.

```ts
    @Component({
       selector: 'somecomp',
       templateUrl: './somecomp.component.html'
    })
    export class SomeComponent implements OnInit{
      private _someService;
      private _route;
      constructor(someService:SomeService,route:ActivatedRoute){ 
         this._someService = someService;
         this._route = route;  
      }

      ngOnInit(){
         this.someService.getColumnModel.subscribe(columnModel=>{

            (<any>jQuery('#grid')).jqGrid({
               colModel : columnModel,
               caption : 'Data Grid',
               url : "http://sampleurl.com/data"
            });
            //custom button
            (<any>jQuery('#grid')).navButtonAdd("#pager",{
                buttonicon:"ui-icon-add",
                onClickButton : () => {
                   alert(this._route);//Route(...)
                   this._route.navigate(["/addPage"]); 
                }   
            });
...
```

On click of this button, it requires navigation to another page as shown. But,that alert comes as undefined and gives the error as  `Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined`.

How to ensure that `this._route` is available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace:

```
function(){
   alert(this._route);//undefined
   this._route.navigate(["/addPage"]); 
}
```

with:

```
() => {
   alert(this._route);//undefined
   this._route.navigate(["/addPage"]); 
}
```

Otherwise `this` refers to the object passed as second argument of the `navButtonAdd` function

Comment: hey, good catch! `this` context will change.  But, `onClickButton : () => {...}` gives me a compile error.

Comment: @amdg Can you provide more details?

Comment: I have added more details. Although, the alert appears correctly, I get `TypeError: _this._route.navigate is not a function`

Comment: Ok I just figured the problem out. You inject `ActivatedRoute` but you need `Router`